# Sequential pattern mining on mutiple sequences

Tags: sequence-analysis, sequential-pattern-mining

Can someone give me a hint about a good approach to find a frequent patterns in a multiple sequences.

Each sequences is a combination of 7 characters M,E,N,S,U,R,G. The length of each sequences is different. An example of one such sequences is:

MMSENEMSNMMEMMEMMSSMMMEMMMSMMEMMSSMEMMSMMMEMSMMMEMSMEMSMMMMMMMMMEMSMEMSMMMEMSMMMMMMMMMMEMSMEMSMENNMSMEMSMEMMSMMMESMEMMMSMMEMEMSSMEMMMMMMSMGSMGSMGSMMGSMGSMMEMMSGSMMMNSMGSMMMEMMMMMSMMMGSMNRMGSMNSGSMGSMMEMMNSMGSMMSMGSMEMMMSGSMEGSMERRGSMGSMMMMMNEMMNSMMNSMMMSMGSMGSMMEMSGSMMMMMMMMMMRGSMMRGSMRGSMRGSMMRGSMNRRESNMMMMRGSMMSGSMRRRRUGSMMNRRNEMSSGSMRGSMEMSRRMRRUGSMMMMMNMMMMMMMSMGSMMRRMRRUMMNGSMRRMMUMRRMNSNRMUUUMUMUUMMMUUMMSNUUMUMMUMMMMGGRRRRRRUGSRGSMUSMMURRUSMMMMMMNGSRRRUMMMUMGSMMNRRRUSMMMMMNRRRUGSMMGRRRRRRUGSMRRMUUGSMMMNSRRGSMMMMMMRRMMRRRRUGSMRRMUGSMEMGSMMSRGSMRRUMMMRRUGSMMMUSMNUUSRUMUMUSMMMMMESRRMUMRGSMMMNNMSSRGSMGSMNRRRRRRRUGSMMNNSRGSMMRRMMRRMMMMMMMMRGSMMRRMRRMMMMMRRMMMMMRRMMMNSNMSMMUURRUMMMMRRMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMUUMMNUUUUMUMMMUMMMSSUURUUUSNUUURUUUMUUUMMMMUUMMMMMMMMUMMMMMMUMMMMMMMMUMMMMMMMMSNRMMUMMMMMUMMMENRUMMUMMUMMEUMMMMRRMNMMSMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMUMMNRUMMUUMMUUMMUMMMMMMMUMMMUMMUMMUMUMMMMMMMMMUMMUUUUUMMMMMMMMMMMM

I am looking for a method that can detect frequent patterns in this ordered sequence.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Well there are some long sequences of M's there, but are those really what you're looking for?  What is your definition of a "frequent pattern"?

Comment: For example, I want to find the frequent subsequences. Like Apriori algorithm does, but I want to use multiple strings as inputs and find the subsequens that have minimum support. Do I make sense ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have an answer for this, but perhaps I can help you clarify the question a bit more.  Say a pattern, $P$, has support $n$ if it's contained in exactly $n$ sequences: write $s(P)=n$.  Say a pattern is $n$-maximal if $s(P)\ge n$ and $s(Q)<n$ for all patterns $Q$ containing $P$.  Given some $n$, you want to find all $n$-maximal patterns, right? -- and roughly how many sequences, of what sort of length, are we talking about?